# SharePoint 2013 Service Pack 1 Installation Error - 'There are no products affected by this package installed on this system'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, error, installation, service-pack

I have SharePoint 2013 Installed with version '15.0.4420.1017' as per [Steve Chen's Page](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2013/03/26/3561010.aspx) the version I have is RTM. So in order to get my workflow working [As guided by Yevgeniy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345600/visual-studio-2012-wont-deploy-my-sharepoint-2013-workflow-in-an-app) I have to installed SP1 on top of this version.

When I try to run and install the 'officeserversp2013-kb2880552-fullfile-x64-en-us.exe' file. I get the below given error message.

[image]

Any idea how to get rid of this and install the SP1? I need to get the Workflow working.

**Update 1:**

Apparently I have already installed SP1 but the version still remains the old. See the screen shot.

[image]

**Update 2:**

Performed a configuration cache cleanup via [The Cache Remover - CodePlex Tool](https://spcachecleaner.codeplex.com/). Still no luck. The version still remains '15.0.4420.1017'

Comment: Is it already installed? 
You can also try to Restart the SP timer services and do an IIS reset and then try to install again.

Comment: @Robban1980 SP Times Job restart and IISReset did not work... Well I believe i havent installed it yet IF i have it installed, it will show me the updated version in my 'Manage Servers in this Farm' yeah? Right now it says 'Configuration database version: 15.0.4420.1017'.

Comment: @Robban1980 Did u mean whether the SP1 is already installed or not? If so... Answer is yes! See my update above.

Comment: Did you run the SharePoint Product Configuration Wizard after installation? Also check in Central Administration->Upgrade and Migration > Review Database Status for current update status

Answer (score 2):

Open a command prompt run as administrator and run

```
officeserversp2013-kb2880552-fullfile-x64-en-us.exe PACKAGE.BYPASS.DETECTION.CHECK=1
```

Source
http://www.windowstechinfo.com/2013/09/solved-outlook2010-kb2459115-fullfile.html

Answer (score 0):

Fix: I removed all of the security updates that were applied the same day I installed SP1, restarted the server, and was allowed to run the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard immediately following the restart.

Comment: Can someone confirm this please?